# Translating code for DLL Injection from Delphi 7 to Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe2, code-injection

I got an old injector which was made by me in Delphi 7 and I tried to change him in that way, that it still works in XE2 but i failed-.- The new test dll works with my old injector without any problems so im quite sure that my injector got a bug.

here is the code I made:

```
procedure TForm1.InjectDLL(const ADLLName: String; targetproc: Cardinal);
var
  dllname: String;
  pDLLname, pStartAddr: Pointer;
  bw: NativeUInt;
  hProcess, hRemoteThread: THandle;
  TID: Cardinal;
begin
  hProcess := OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, targetproc);
  pDLLname := VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, 0, length(dllname) + 1,
    MEM_COMMIT or MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

  WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, pDLLname, Pointer(dllname),
    length(dllname) + 1, bw);

  pStartAddr := GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle('kernel32.dll'), 'LoadLibraryA');
  hRemoteThread := CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, nil, 0, pStartAddr,
    pDLLname, 0, TID);
  WaitForSingleObject(hRemoteThread, INFINITE);
  showmessage('Fehler ' + IntToStr(GetLastError) + ': ' +
    SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
  CloseHandle(hProcess);
end;
```

I just needed to change hProcess and hRemoteThread to THandle and bw to NativeUInt. The showmessage just tells me that all works. There must be a small difference since the String type changed from d7 to XE2. I also tried to cast the dll name as PAnsiChar but it changed nothing to me.

Hope I posted enough information for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The net result of your code, under Unicode Delphi, is to pass UTF-16 text to `LoadLibraryA`. And of course, that expects 8 bit ANSI text. You have two options to resolve the problem:

1. Stick with ANSI text and simply replace `string` with `AnsiString` in your code snippet.
2. Switch to Unicode text. Use `LoadLibraryW` and apply the change suggested by Arnaud to correctly handle the length of the 16 bit text.

Comment: I use the version 2 to get this working im using xe2 anyway(delphi 7 is deinstalled). Thanks a lot guys :D.

Comment: Option 1 would work fine on XE2 as it happens, but Unicode option is always to be preferred.

Answer (score 4):

In Delphi XE2, `string` is now made of `Widechar`, i.e. `char=WideChar`.

So you should write: `(length(dllname)+1)*sizeof(char)` in your code. It will work for both Delphi 7 and XE2.

And 'LoadLibraryW' for unicode parameter.

Comment: added dllname:=ADLLName; (just forgot it in my quotation) and pDLLname := VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, nil, (length(dllname) + 1) *
    sizeof(char), MEM_COMMIT or MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

 WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, pDLLname, Pointer(dllname),
    (length(dllname) + 1) * sizeof(char), bw);

still doesnt work to me :/

Comment: @arnaud That's not really going to do it. The thing at the other end of the WriteProcessMemory is going to expect 8 bit text. The simplest way to fix this is to replace string with AnsiString.